# Phonegap Media.play

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to set up a PhoneGap app on Android using the [Media](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media) object. But no audio is being played on my Android device for some reason.

The source code of the HTML file is:

```
<input type="button" onclick="playAudio()" value="Play Sound">

<script>
    function playAudio() {
        var my_media = new Media("http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples/3721.mp3");
        my_media.play();
    }
</script>
```

I have added the plugin and site whitelisting to the config.xml file like this:

```
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = XXXX
    version     = "0.1.0" >

<gap:platform name="android" />

<plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler" />

<access origin="http://www.noiseaddicts.com" />

</widget>
```

Any idea of what I could have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not create the right file structure when I created the project and was missing critical files including the cordova.js file. I started over from the beginning according to cordova documentation and got it working then.

Answer (score 0):

You should attach success and error handlers to be able to debug what is going on.

```
var my_media = new Media("http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples/3721.mp3",
        // success callback
        function () {
            alert("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function (err) {
            alert("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        }
);
my_media.play();
```

Update: If this is not working try doing the following. In app/res/xml/config.xml:

```
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
</feature>
```

In app/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

which is specified here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media_accessing_the_feature

Comment: Thanks. This code gave me no output but when I run `try { var my_media = new Media("http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples/3721.mp3"); my_media.play(); } catch(err) { alert (err); }` I got a _Media is not defined_ error. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: thanks. I have loaded the AudioHandler and had already enables all permissions but the problems remains. Any other ideas?

Comment: Actually it works for some reason when I load [cordova.js](https://github.com/Erez-IL/sample-handbell/blob/master/cordova.js).